# How to customize emacs in python mode to highlight operators?

Tags: emacs

I'm setting up emacs to be my python IDE, and I've found plenty of material online that explain auto-completion, among a variety of other features. What I can't figure out, though, is how to get the syntax highlighter to do its highlighting magic on operators.

How can I customize my emacs in python mode to make + - different colors? I'd also like it to make integers, floats, and parentheses different colors as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following in your ~/.emacs file:

```
;
; Python operator and integer highlighting
; Integers are given font lock's "constant" face since that's unused in python
; Operators, brackets are given "widget-inactive-face" for convenience to end-user 
;

(font-lock-add-keywords 'python-mode
    '(("\\<\\(object\\|str\\|else\\|except\\|finally\\|try\\|\\)\\>" 0 py-builtins-face)  ; adds object and str and fixes it so that keywords that often appear with : are assigned as builtin-face
    ("\\<[\\+-]?[0-9]+\\(.[0-9]+\\)?\\>" 0 'font-lock-constant-face) ; FIXME: negative or positive prefixes do not highlight to this regexp but does to one below
    ("\\([][{}()~^<>:=,.\\+*/%-]\\)" 0 'widget-inactive-face)))
```

Answer (score 5):

i actually have something like this setup for my programming modes.  this defines 2 separate faces, one for operators and one for the "end statement" symbol (not so useful in python, obviously).  you can modify the `"\\([][|!.+=&/%*,<>(){}:^~-]+\\)"` regex to match the operators you are interested in and customize the faces to be the color you want.

```
(defvar font-lock-operator-face 'font-lock-operator-face)

(defface font-lock-operator-face
  '((((type tty) (class color)) nil)
    (((class color) (background light))
     (:foreground "dark red"))
    (t nil))
  "Used for operators."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defvar font-lock-end-statement-face 'font-lock-end-statement-face)

(defface font-lock-end-statement-face
  '((((type tty) (class color)) nil)
    (((class color) (background light))
     (:foreground "DarkSlateBlue"))
    (t nil))
  "Used for end statement symbols."
  :group 'font-lock-faces)

(defvar font-lock-operator-keywords
  '(("\\([][|!.+=&/%*,<>(){}:^~-]+\\)" 1 font-lock-operator-face)
    (";" 0 font-lock-end-statement-face)))
```

then, you just enable this by adding a hook to the relevant modes (this example assumes you are using "python-mode"):

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
                  '(lambda ()
                     (font-lock-add-keywords nil font-lock-operator-keywords t))
                  t t)
```

Comment: I've copied and pasted the text here to my .emacs file and running it in python mode, and it doesn't change the syntax highlighting. Typing a semi-colon, for example, doesn't result in a highlight. I don't enough about customizing emacs to troubleshoot it, though ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: when your cursor is over an operator, type "M-x describe-faces".  does this list the font-lock-operator-face?

Comment: oops, i meant "M-x describe-text-properties".

Comment: Nope. It just says fontified t.

Comment: if you run "M-x describe-variable font-lock-keywords", do you see the font-lock-operator stuff listed in the value of this variable?  and, if you run "M-x describe-variable python-mode-hook" do you also see the operator stuff?  (note, i'm assuming you have _enabled_ font lock mode).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've played around by putting in ~/.emacs file: (font-lock-add-keywords 'python-mode
    '(("\\<\\(object\\|str\\)\\>" 1 py-pseudo-keyword-face prepend))
    '(("\\([][{}:-]\\)" 1 py-pseduo-keyword-face prepend))) and I find the first object|str regexp in the variable but not the second one. Emacs is quite difficult to troubleshoot on one's own!

Comment: Ah. Turns out my problem was complete ignorance of lisp, not of emacs. I've figured it out now thanks very much for your time.

Comment: It did not make any change on my end :-(

Comment: @alper how did you configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding my own answer since I couldn't get the others working (as of emacs 25.3.1, 2017).

The following elisp can be used to highlight operators:

```
;; Operator Fonts
(defface font-lock-operator-face
 '((t (:foreground "#8b8bcd"))) "Basic face for operator." :group 'basic-faces)

;; C-Like
(dolist (mode-iter '(c-mode c++-mode glsl-mode java-mode javascript-mode rust-mode))
  (font-lock-add-keywords mode-iter
   '(("\\([~^&\|!<>=,.\\+*/%-]\\)" 0 'font-lock-operator-face keep))))
;; Scripting
(dolist (mode-iter '(python-mode lua-mode))
  (font-lock-add-keywords mode-iter
   '(("\\([@~^&\|!<>:=,.\\+*/%-]\\)" 0 'font-lock-operator-face keep))))
```